# Scope for multiply models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a page (promote) for the models breakfast, apartment and villa.  The idea is to make a scope to combine these models in one scope where the attribute `promote` is `true` and sort by the attribute `sorting`  Is that possibly?

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless these models are UNION-compatible, you cannot perform the query in a single statement, but you will need three different queries.

Assuming these models are different, what you can do is

```
(Villa.where(promote: true).to_a +
 Apartment.where(promote: true).to_a +     
 Breakfast.where(promote: true).to_a).sort_by(&:sorting)
```

Starting from this statement, there are plenty of ways to write it more elegantly, including scopes, custom functions, etc.

```
def promotions(*models)
  models.inject([]) do |records, model|
    records += model.where(promote: true).to_a
  end.sort_by(&:sorting)
end

promotions(Villa, Apartment, Breakfast)
# => [..., ..., ...]
```